# How to modify a bash alias to take input from the terminal?

Tags: bash, alias

In my `.bashrc`, I have aliases:

```
#Custom aliases
alias gta="git add -A"
alias gtc="git commit -m 'Added files' "
```

I want to create a new alias that does the command `git push origin <branch name>`.
Earlier it was easy because it was always set to `git push origin master`.

But now , GitHub has changed `master` to `main` for all repositories created after October 2020.
Now what I want is that I want to set an alias `gtp` and it asks me a prompt to use `main` or `master`.
Depending on the selection, I want the appropriate commands to be executed.

P.S: I know that we can make 2 aliases , one for `master` and one for `main`, but just out of curiosity, how to solve the above problem?

Comment: I would use a function in .bashrc (or a shellscript somewhere in PATH) for this purpose.

Comment: Wouldn't it be simpler to set a default upstream branch for each of your branches? Than you can just `alias gtp="git push"`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could add something like this in your `.bashrc`:

```
alias gtp=f

f() {
  arg="$1"
  if [[ -z "$arg" ]] || [[ "$arg" != main && "$arg" != master ]]; then
    echo "Bad argument"
  else
    git push origin "$arg"
  fi
}
```

Then

```
~$ . .bashrc
```

```
$ gtp
Bad argument

$ gtp foo
Bad argument

$ gtp main
<git doing it's thing>

$ gtp master
<git doing it's thing>
```

Or [@Kusalananda's suggestion](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/615415/how-to-modify-the-bashrc-to-take-input-from-the-terminal/615432#comment1150739_615432)

```
f() {
    arg="$1"

    case $arg in
        main|master)
            git push origin "$arg"
            ;;
        *)
            echo error >&2
    esac
}
```

Comment: or `case $arg in (main|master) git push origin "$arg";; (*) echo error >&2; esac`.

Comment: @Kusalananda better